# Setting a place for the ushpizin in the sukkah

Tags: sukkot, sukkah

I've been by many sukkos where after the bal habayis (bal hasukkah?) "invites" the ushpizin they will then set a place for them (whichever one is supposed to come that night.) The "place" they set is simply leaving a chair open somewhere by the table or within the sukkah. What is the source for this minhag?

Comment: I wonder if this is older or newer than Eliyahu's chair at the seder and brit.

Comment: Don't all seven come each time? That's what the invitation in _sidurim_ seems to indicate. (Perhaps the householder intends them to share a chair. `:-)` )

Answer (score 7):

[Nitei Gavriel Sukkah 37:6:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46442&st=&pgnum=198) says that some have a Minhag to place a special chair for the Ushpizin. He mentions it the name of the Chida - [Avodas Hakodesh 289](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41866&hilite=5bea232f-b676-4a2c-a201-b052cc5471d3&st=%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9F&pgnum=22) - He also mentions it in the name of the [Kaf HaChaim 639:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14425&st=&pgnum=183). Kaf HaChaim 639:8 mentions it from the Zohar Parshas Lech Lecha 93:1. Sefer Be'er Miriam says he saw the Chida do so.